# Ctrl+b appearing as '^B' at command line

Tags: zsh, tmux, iterm2

I noticed this behavior in tmux, but it also happens when I have no session attached. Instead of entering as the command key binding `Ctrl+b`, `^B` is printed to the command line. I don't have a .tmux.config file. I am using iterm2 with zsh. Not sure what is going on... any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The shell is interpreting the Ctrl-B as input because it has no special meaning as your shell is currently configured.  Most likely, your shell is set up to use `vi` style key bindings or are using non-standard key bindings.

The `^B` you're getting is what's known as caret notation, and is the de-facto standard in most UNIX applications for representing control codes in a textual form.  Wikipedia has a somewhat terse but still informative page on [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) that may be of interest to you.  You can produce similar results with  most letters and a handful of other characters by hitting Ctrl-V prior to entering the desired key sequence (Ctrl-V tells the shell to treat the next byte of input as a literal value instead of a hotkey).